# Use PHP to inject HTML into <div> before page renders?

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a child theme based on Jupiter and need to append some HTML to the end of a div generated by Jupiter's theme files. Problem is, this div is generated in multiple theme files, and I don't want to copy-paste my HTML into multiple theme files.

In a nutshell:

```
<div class="mk-header-holder"><!-- this is the div generated by Jupiter, but across multiple theme files-->

   <!-- Some HTML generated by Jupiter -->

   <div class="my-custom-code"><!-- I want to add this with PHP if possible, regardless of which theme file is loaded-->
   </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible with PHP using WordPress, or will I have to rely on jQuery?

Comment: I would either contact the theme author or see whether there are any hooks within the theme that you could use. Perhaps instead of editing a bunch of theme files, there's an action or filter that is always run in that area, to where you could add the div into the actual HTML/PHP.

Comment: If there weren't a hook, is it still possible to do this with PHP/WordPress core features, or do you think I'd need to rely on JavaScript?

Comment: It just depends on how the theme is coded. Looks like a premium theme so there's no way to tell as an outsider. If there's no hook, perhaps there's a sidebar or a template part, something that's called from all of the various locations. Look for code that's identical across all the different files.

Comment: You'll also want to make sure to create a child theme regardless of which approach you take. That way when updates are released, your changes won't be lost.

Comment: It's possible using [output buffers](http://php.net/manual/function.ob-start.php). Basically, you capture all the output, then change it.

Comment: Append your HTML, PHP, SCRIPT in one of the multiple files using a shortcode, hook or adding a template part. I do this every week with premium templates.